# Executor service is gets stuck, Not throwing error

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, rest

when i call the below method recursively it is getting stucked and not throwing error. not giving any response. thread pool size is 50. when processing 100K records i am facing this issue.
how to solve this?
Thanks in Advance

```
public void processActivityDeposits(
    Activity activity) {
  int partitionSize =
      environment.getProperty("patition.size", Integer.class, 1000);
  List<Long> records =
      service.findReadyToProcessRecords(
          activity.getActivityId(),
          partitionSize);
  if (records != null && records.size() > 0) {
    try {
      int threadPoolSize =
          environment.getProperty("thread.pool.size", Integer.class, 10);
      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
      for (Long activityId : records) {
        executorService.execute(
            new ActivityDepositInternalProcessor(
                activityId));
      }
      executorService.shutdown();
      try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      processActivityDeposits(
          activity);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how many core does the cpu have? arbitrarily setting any thread size limit will result in degrading performance.reduce the number of threads and try it out..that will probably help..else more time will get wasted in context switching between threads.

Comment: Calling that method recursively will each time create a new thread pool. Not sure if that really is what you want. Eventually, you will overwhelm your CPU with all those threads and performance will go down instead of up.

Comment: Why are you creating a new executor on each recursion?  That's potentially a lot of overhead.

Comment: @M.Deinum there are lot of records to process so taking each time 1000 and again processing remaining so doing recursive .
what is the best way to process huge no of records with performance ?

Comment: @akshayapandey the cpu has 1 core

Comment: @Taylor  there are lot of records to process so taking each time 1000 and again processing remaining so doing recursive .

Comment: Right, but the overhead of executor creation and destruction, and underlying threads is not trivial at significant numbers of recursions.  In short, the executor is reusable across recursions.  If you're just trying to "drain" the task queue before the next, track the returned `Future`s and wait their completion before the next recursion.

Comment: First make your code work with a single thread. If you use JPA the use appropriate flush and clear tactics to keep performance up. Also tune the JDBC fetch size to reduce the network overhead of JDBC (default is generally 10). With that you probably gain more performance than creating a lot of threads on a single CPU with a couple of cores.

Comment: Do you mean to always recurse on the same `activity` object?  I don't see anything ever assigned to that variable.

Comment: Also, is `ActivityDepositInternalProcessor` the class we're looking at?  If so, you're creating executors from within executors (geometric progression) and you'll end up with a huge amount of threads. With enough of these, your cpu is doing nothing but managing and scheduling the threads, meaning no useful work, hence you're getting "stuck". I'd encourage you to separate the executor management from the "work" it's doing, you've got a lot of concerns here in one method and I think that could be your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following changes to your code.
a. move the execution service creation and shutdown out of the if block.

b. Do not set the thread pool size more than 5 as you have only one core,

```
 public void processActivityDeposits(
    Activity activity) {
  int partitionSize =
      environment.getProperty("patition.size", Integer.class, 1000);
  List<Long> records =
      service.findReadyToProcessRecords(
          activity.getActivityId(),
          partitionSize);
        //moved out of if block
       int threadPoolSize =
          environment.getProperty("thread.pool.size", Integer.class, 10);
      ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);     
  if (records != null && records.size() > 0) {
    try {

      for (Long activityId : records) {
        executorService.execute(
            new ActivityDepositInternalProcessor(
                activityId));
      }
     
      processActivityDeposits(
          activity);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  //moved out of if block
   executorService.shutdown();
      try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: looks like here doing recursive, maybe your suggestion not workout.